# How to use modernizr to make firefox support google OpenSans font?

Tags: firefox, fonts, modernizr

I am using google Opensans font. It works fine in almost all browser except Firefox.

Should I use Modernizr? If it is, then how can I do it?

Edited: I've update firefox to 29.1. But still not working. Here is a demo in codepen. See, it's not displaying `opensans`.

[image]

Comment: in what way is it not working in firefox?

Comment: I am using `!imporant` in css to override all `font-family`. Here is the css `div
{
font-family: 'Open Sans', verdana, sans-serif !important;
}` Firefox displays `verdana`.

Comment: What is your CSS, what is your specific version of Firefox?  I would guess you aren't using the proper webfont file type, or possibly not serving them with the correct mime type

Comment: I'm using Firefox version 28.0. I'm fetching the font using `<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans|Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`.

Comment: that looks like opensans. change sans-serif to serif to make it more obvious that the font isn't loading, also, it would be great if you could post the actual link rather than an image

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rIxCL. In my google chrome browser it looks like opensans but not in my firefox.

Comment: http://cl.ly/image/3J350v2e0y18 - both are loading fine, have you checked your network tab to see if it is loading properly? The posted image is still opensans

Answer (score 0):

just loading the font and using it works fine in firefox 28, so more than likely there is something else going on. Can you post a codepen/jsfiddle showing the issue?

[image]

Comment: I've uploaded an image in my question 'of the code in my firefox browser'.